# How to slice a findall result from Pandas, Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would like to extract using a specific pattern from a column of worksheet names which were extracted from excel spreadsheets, and only retrieve the last result from the list of results.

For example:

```
"<Worksheet ""2012"">"
"<Worksheet ""2012"">"
"<Worksheet ""2012"">"
"<Worksheet ""2012 - 2013"">"
"<Worksheet ""2012 - 13"">"
"<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">"
"<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">"
"<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">"
"<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">"
"<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">"
"<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">"
"<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">"
"<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">"
"<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">"
"<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">"
```

I want to extract the twelve from 2011-2012 for example, from the worksheet column.

I would like to use the following code in order to extract the last two digits that match the pattern, however I get an error:
*Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex*

```
df['worksheet'].str.findall('\d{2}')[:,-1]
```

How can I correctly extract using the pattern from the worksheet column and only retrieve the last instance?

The result should look like:

```
12
12
12
13
13
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `.str` accessor, you can access parts of a list with indexing or using the `get` method.

I think you are looking for:

```
df['worksheet'] = df['worksheet'].str.findall('\d{2}').str[-1]
```

Output:

```
0     12
1     12
2     12
3     13
4     13
5     12
6     12
7     12
8     12
9     12
10    12
11    12
12    12
13    12
14    12
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so :

```
df['worksheet'] = df['worksheet'].astype(str).str[-4:-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to access the lists in your findall result like:

#### Code:

```
df['worksheet'].str.findall('\d{2}').map(lambda x: x[-1])
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import math

df = pd.DataFrame([
    "<Worksheet ""2012"">",
    "<Worksheet ""2012"">",
    "<Worksheet ""2012"">",
    "<Worksheet ""2012 - 2013"">",
    "<Worksheet ""2012 - 13"">",
    "<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">",
    "<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">",
    "<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">",
    "<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">",
    "<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">",
    "<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">",
    "<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">",
    "<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">",
    "<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">",
    "<Worksheet ""2011-2012"">",
], columns=['worksheet'])
print(df)

print(df['worksheet'].str.findall('\d{2}').map(lambda x: x[-1]))
```

#### Results:

```
                  worksheet
0          <Worksheet 2012>
1          <Worksheet 2012>
2          <Worksheet 2012>
3   <Worksheet 2012 - 2013>
4     <Worksheet 2012 - 13>
5     <Worksheet 2011-2012>
6     <Worksheet 2011-2012>
7     <Worksheet 2011-2012>
8     <Worksheet 2011-2012>
9     <Worksheet 2011-2012>
10    <Worksheet 2011-2012>
11    <Worksheet 2011-2012>
12    <Worksheet 2011-2012>
13    <Worksheet 2011-2012>
14    <Worksheet 2011-2012>

0     12
1     12
2     12
3     13
4     13
5     12
6     12
7     12
8     12
9     12
10    12
11    12
12    12
13    12
14    12
Name: worksheet, dtype: object
```